# Pagination with populated data in mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm struggling with a problem of fetching data from DB and applying "pagination" functionality. My case is that I have webstore with multiple users. Every user can publish their profile and create their products. On the website, I'd like to show the products of users who did publish their profiles.

Currently, this is my code:

```
    Product.find({ active: true, deleted: false })
        .sort({ created: -1 })
        .populate({
          path: 'user',
          match: { isPublished: true },
          select: 'details slug name',
        })
        .exec((error, products) => {
            if (error) {
                return response.status(500).send({ error: 'There was an error.' });
            }

            if (products === null) {
                return response.status(404).send({ error: 'Products not found.' });
            }

            const productsWithPublishedTrainerProfile = _.filter(products, product => !_.isNull(product.user));

            return response.status(200).send(_.map(productsWithPublishedTrainerProfile, product => mapProduct(product)));
        });
```

It works - It fetches all the active products, populate the user who created the product and if their profile is published then the product is not filtered out.

Now I need to implement "pagination" functionality which means that I want to use `.skip()` and `.limit()` functions but this skip/limit will be run on all the products (not only the filtered ones.) what means that the endpoint won't be returning the exact number of products (set in the `limit()` function.

I wonder if there is any solution for that. I read about `.aggregate` with setting `$lookup`, `$skip` and `$limit` but after hours of fighting with it I couldn't make it work.

I will really appreciate any help ✌️

Comment: Do you need the unpublished items to be returned?  i.e. can you search for `{ active: true, deleted: false, isPublished: true }`

Comment: No. I need to return items created by users who did publish their *profiles*. The product document doesn't have `isPublished` property.